# Vibration on cold water pipe into boiler mate

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I’ve searched but can’t find my exact problem. We have a boiler mate for our hot water. When running either shower, the cold water pipe into the boiler mate vibrates causing a water hammer like issue. We can get it to (mostly) stop by adjusting the temp of the shower. If we use the hot water anywhere else in the house it will start again upon turning off the non shower faucet.

We’re on a well and the pump is good. So far we’ve drained the tank to remove sediment and added an expansion tank. We just had the water filtration system cleaned. Thought that might be the problem because the filter was overdue but now that is brand new as well. It seems like after any work is done it’ll be better for a day or so and then starts with the problem again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the pipe have a length that is not supported well or could be supported better?

Comment: There is a good length that goes straight down. I’ll have to look into that further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does the Boilermate include a thermostatic mixing valve to temper the hot water? It could look like this:

[image: e]

Or like this (before installation):

[image: e]

If so, these valves sometimes vibrate under certain settings of temperature and flow rate. To see if this is the issue, you can try grasping the valve with your hand protected by a thick towel, and see if it's the valve that is vibrating.

You can try adjusting the temperature knob all the way hot, then all the way cold, then return to the original setting (but not while someone is showering). This may un-stick an internal part that is sticking and vibrating. There are also rebuild kits available for some models to replace internal parts that have become worn.

If you can't turn the knob at all, the internals may be caked with minerals. If that's the case it needs to be rebuilt or replaced, as it is no longer able to control water temperature.

Photo 1: boilermate-repairs.co.uk

Photo 2: Ebay

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but we don’t have that part